# how can i sort jqgrid data using loadonce:true and rownum:5

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

i now learned that the only way to sort client side is to set `loadonce:true,`..BUT if i set it to true, then i would not be able to navigate page, and if i set my `rownum` less than the number of data, it will not display the other data.
example, if i going to code this:

```
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList:[5,10,50,100],                          
    pager: '#tblDataPager',
    sortname: 'main_account_group_desc',                        
    rowNum:5,
    loadonce:true
```

and my data is more than 5, it will only show the first 5 of my data, no paging, but my sorting is ok. and if im going to change the code into this :

```
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList:[5,10,50,100],                          
    pager: '#tblDataPager',
    sortname: 'main_account_group_desc',                        
    rowNum:5,
    loadonce:false
```

it will display 5 data on the jqgrid, there's a page navigation (next, previous, last, first) but the sorting wont function everytime i clicked the column header.

is there a way that i can set my `rownum:5` and navigate to the next data using paging while setting the `loadonce:true` to enable sorting? can anybody in here who can help me? thank you

Comment: I am sure that you have some error in the definition of the jqGrid. The local paging work exactly like the local sorting if you use `loadonce:true`. If you include full definition of the jqGrid I will help you to find the error. More better if you included additionally the JSON data from the server response. You can capture the data with respect of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 1):

hai friend When u r saying loadonce:true then data load into jqgrid only one time. so after that what ever operation (navigation,sorting and so on) done by user that is perform in client side only.i.e that is not load the data from server side .so all client side operations (like sorting) working fine.

but When u r saying loadonce:false then every time it il bring the server side data so you feel like sorting is not working. you can handle it in your server side coding.

```
            loadonce:true  => first time only data load from server 
            loadonce:false => all the time data load from server
```

Thank you